# Shortcode to include PHP file, pass various parameters to include?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, include, parameter

Want to include php file in WP content. Some parameters will be different depending on the include.

I want to write 1 include shortcode. I **do not** want to write different include functions for each include file.

Example shortcodes:

[include filepath='/includes/dogs.php' color='black' size='large']

[include filepath='/includes/table.php' type='dogs' number='5' sort='desc']

After the function includes the file, all other parameters are passed to **THAT file**. Is this possible?

This code is close except for grabbing all other parameters for the include:

```
// SHORTCODE - Include File
// http://www.amberpanther.com/knowledge-base/using-the-wordpress-shortcode-api-to-include-an-external-file-in-the-post-content/
```

+

```
function include_file($atts) {
  //check the input and override the default filepath NULL
  //if filepath was specified
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('filepath' => 'NULL'), $atts));
  //check if the filepath was specified and if the file exists
  if ($filepath!='NULL' && file_exists(CHILD_SS_DIR.$filepath)){
  //turno on output buffering to capture script output
  ob_start();
  //include the specified file
  include(CHILD_SS_DIR.$filepath);
  //assign the file output to $content variable and clean buffer
  $content = ob_get_clean();
  //return the $content
  //return is important for the output to appear at the correct position
  //in the content
  return $content;
  }
}
//register the Shortcode handler
add_shortcode('include', 'include_file');
```

Want something safer than using a PHP wrapper plugin! Thank you in advance.

**Clarifications** The above is example code, I'm not sure I'll even use it. Shortcode parameter 1 is the include file. Any parameter following this should be accessible to the include itself.

**Why do this?** I don't know any way of including content from an DB or file outside WP without using a risky PHP interpreting plugin like Insert_PHP or Allow PHP in Pages. These plugins allow *any* PHP code to run, a security risk. I only want to pass parameters to each include file.

**Explain your Example**

[include filepath='/includes/dogs.php' color='black' size='large']

Filepath is the include (dogs.php). When dogs.php is included, $color = "black" and $size = "large" for the code on dogs.php

I want the function to pass any parameters after filepath to the include. This means I don't have to write a function for each different include.

**This is a Bad Idea**

Please offer a better solution. I am not a WP developer. I have enough PHP knowledge to write custom functions, but admittedly lack a comprehensive understanding of all things WP.

The basis for my question was observing many WP plugins with shortcodes. They essentially do I what I am asking: parameters are passed and content is produced.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I don't understand "all other parameters". can you show a example ?

Comment: You want to include php-files, but want something safer than including php files?

Comment: what a horrible idea. regardless that this way it will be easy for you to break the site without being able to recover, and you will not be able to maintain the code, there is the simple fact that shortcodes should be content macos and not a half arsed programming language

Comment: @mmm I provided examples shortcodes above. First parameter is the include file, anything after should be passed to the include.

Comment: @janh2 using a PHP interpreter like insert_php plugin means anyone can run ANY code inside my posts. I wanted to only run an include. [insert_php][/insert_php] is less secure than calling an include alone.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Is there a better way to include dynamic content from a database or php file outside WP in posts? Running a php interpreter like Insert_php is risky because it allows ANY code to run. At least a shortcode include limits the security risks.

Comment: when you use `include` or `require`, the scope doesn't change then the variable `$atts` with all parameters is accessible in the PHP file.

Comment: Ok. From this example: [include filepath='/includes/dogs.php' color='black' size='large'] I want the include file to consider $color = 'black' and $size = 'large'. Does that mean $atts could be an array which the include can access? Or change the function to treat anything after the filepath as variables for the include? Thanks for replying, btw.

Comment: not likely. when you want to be fully dynamic the only way to do it is by inventing your own programing language

Comment: @MarkKaplun Fair enough, understood. The basis for my question was observing many WP plugins with shortcodes. They essentially do I what I am asking: parameters are passed and content is produced. I was hoping to combine that with an include file.

Comment: many wordpress plugins are crap (you may quote me ;) ) wordpress core is very forgiving but just because you can do something do not mean you should do it. In this case it is simple principal of separating code from content. code should be tracked in git, content in the DB. Finding in the DB where a code is used is an annoying task and the more iterations your site will have the more likely you will be to actually need to do it

Comment: you know in advance what your includes are going to do, just have each of them register its own shortcode. With a "formal" restrictive type of API a clearly defined shortcode attributes will force you into, it is less likely that you will have to hunt for their usage to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments and guidance. I implemented solutions which didn't reinvent the wheel.

The complication was finding a way to remove the [insert_php][/insert_php] wrapped code from pages and posts and still preserve the content and user experience.

**Custom Template Pages**

Pages and Posts which were *almost entirely* PHP were made into custom template files. These were placed into my child theme folder. Old posts and pages were updated to the custom templates.

For large websites, I suggest writing a command line script to bulk update post templates. Or, use a good plugin.

**Created Short Codes for Content Snippets**

All instances of PHP includes, tables and DB calls within posts and pages were rewritten as short codes. These codes were added to my child theme's functions.php file.

This preserved essential tables, ads and images. Also, I removed text from within the PHP wrapper and placed it back into the WP content. This makes for much easier content management and integration with helpful plugins like Yoast SEO.

**Easier to update content**

I've found periodically re-coding my content functions improves efficiency and maintenance. It's similar to editing and rewriting written prose.

Making these changes was lengthy. However it will be much easier to update content snippets in the future!

**Faster Website**

Removing the [insert_php][/insert_php] content and plugin improved server performance and page speed. This is critical for SEO. Google Page Speed Insights noted a slight but noticeable improvement in server response time, roughly 0.30 ~ 0.23 for most pages.

Previously the server had to process all WP PHP, then run my own PHP wrapped inside each post. This was redundant and wasted time.

**More Secure**

Running a PHP wrapper inside WP content creates a substantial security vulnerability. Remember, these wrappers allow **any** PHP code to be executed, including MySQL, Exec, etc. commands. This is **dangerous** even if you have secured your WP site and database.

Now my sites are much safer. As an aside, I suggest using 2 Factor authentication for WP login. If someone gets in and runs PHP code (or installs a PHP wrapper plugin and subsequently runs code) you could be in big trouble!

2 Factor login adds an extra layer of security even if you password gets compromised. I recommend a plugin with Google Authenticator.

**Do PHP Plugins Have Any Valid Purpose?**

At this point I'm not sure. Given immense security risks, I wouldn't recommend them for large, high traffic websites.

I definitely would not recommend them if you're including DB logins, passwords and SQL queries to non-WP DBs in your code. If you must, make sure your DB user is limited to one database and "SELECT" queries. **Do NOT give such users global privileges.**

They might be helpful for testing. It is much easier for newbies to use these plugins while experimenting with content and design ideas than custom-coding a template. But I would highly recommend doing so after testing is done.

Finally, if it is possible to limit PHP commands and output, these plugins might be less risky.